# How to read the latest thread of an email in gmail using JavaMail?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

In order to test notifications in our application, I'm verifying these notifications using JavaMail. I have test for notification with and without attachment. The first test runs fine for email without attachment. Once verified, I delete the email and send out another notification with attachment from the application. Now I face the issue. since my Inbox has 1 email but with two threads (first email without attachment and the latest with attachment both have same subject, hence end up as two threads in the same email). My code throws an error since it expects an email with attachment but instead reads one without. This means the earlier notification wasn't deleted correctly? This is how I did it:

```
//If all messages are read, mark the latest read message as deleted
if(folder.getUnreadMessageCount() == 0){
    message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
}

//If any message is marked deleted, delete that message from folder
if(message.isSet(Flags.Flag.DELETED)){
    folder.expunge();
}
```

I have also added the following to be 100% sure that the first notification gets permanently deleted:

```
folder.close(true);
```

Am I missing something? Or is there a way to differentiate a thread in an email?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're deleting the message correctly, but it would be good to turn on session debugging and look at the protocol trace to see what's really going on.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) for instructions.

Comment: I found an alternative to delete emails successfully. Instead of marking the messages as DELETED, I moved them into Trash folder. That did it! no need for expunge.                                            //Get Trash folder to copy messages that are read
    Folder trash = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");
    trash.open(folder.READ_WRITE);                                           //If all messages are read, delete the latest message
    if(folder.getUnreadMessageCount() == 0){
        folder.copyMessages(new Message[] {message}, trash);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and worked like a charm.

```
//Get Trash folder to copy messages that are read 
Folder trash = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");
trash.open(folder.READ_WRITE);

//If all messages are read, delete the latest message 
if(folder.getUnreadMessageCount() == 0)
{
    folder.copyMessages(new Message[] {message}, trash);
}
```